# Excel VBA: Formula with reference to cell in another worksheet (variable)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that links a cell from another worksheet (this is stored as a variable called SheetName). The user is prompted with an Input box to select a cell. I would like to have a cell in another worksheet reference to the selected cell.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Dim WorkRng As Range
    Total1 = "Select Total cell"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", Total1, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("C6").formula = "=" & 'SheetName.Name' & "!" & WorkRng.Address
```

The last line is where I am running into object errors.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Worksheets("WorksheetA").Range("C6").formula = _
   "='" & SheetName.Name & "'!" & WorkRng.Address
```

'note the quote here "='" and here "'!"

Answer (score 1):

Where is sheetname defined? It then needs to be concatenated into the string

```
DIm SheetName As Worksheet
Set SheetName = Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

formula then

```
"=" & SheetName.Name  & "!" & [A1:B2].Address
```

Comment: External includes the worksheet name; in fact it also includes the workbook name and path which Excel evaporates away if unnecessary. You might be duplicating the worksheet name.

Comment: Aghhhh... thanks for letting me know. Was questioning myself. Should have just done some quick homework.